# DNS a-route with SSL and Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, dns

I have a domain served at server A and I have set up an A-record to server B.

For http://mypage.com all works fine.

But there is also SSL on the domain. On server B there are a few virtual hosts set up. One of which has an SSL virtual host (443), theirpage.com. If I now go to https://mypage.com I end up at theirpage.com.

If I set up mypage.com MUST I have the SSL certificate from server A available for this new specific ssl-virualhost? The provider at server A does not share their ssl-certificates...

Comment: Could you please clerify what you mean by "a-routing"? Is that a redirect or is server A serves as proxy forwarding content from server B to requester?

Comment: Oh, not a-routing, a-record is set on server A, where the domain address is “hosted”, which points to server B where the web page is hosted.

Comment: Just so we are on the same page: Server A - runs DNS and Server B - running your web server hosting the content?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming:**

- Server A - DNS only, no web services.
- Server B - Web server.

### The following is extreme oversimplification of what actually happens. For simplicity we exclude all caches, networking and application complexity.

**What happens on the client:**

- User navigates to mypage.com (HTTPS)
- Browser/OS does a lookup of who mypage.com is; receives the IP
- Browser attempts to establish secure connection with IP of a webserver.

It is at this point browser will look at the SSL certificate provided by your web server. That certificate must be signed by trusted authority and have a valid alternate name of mypage.com. Not signed or name does not match to what user typed into the browser you will receive a certificate error.

*If the certificate passed:*

- Browser will complete establishing connection
- Browser will request a content named mypage.com
- Browser displays content revived from the web server

In this scenario only web server must have a valid certificate, prooving to the client that it is indeed the server client attempts to connect to.

HTTP Scenario is similar, but connection is not secured and site will load. Most of the websites setup redirect request on HTTP calls, forcing the user's browser repeat it's request via HTTPS protocol.